# Recursive higher-order function

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, recursion, functional-programming

I have implemented a `through` function for myself in a project.
Since I am still quite new in python and want to learn it correctly, I would be happy about any feedback including style, variable naming...

A first question is how to name the function. Because of [Mathematica's documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html) I called it `through`. Is there a more intuitive name?

```
def through(list_of_functions, value, recurse_level=np.infty):
    """Calls each function in a list

    This function is passing the value as argument to each function
    in a list.
    For a one dimensional list consisting of
    only functions it is equivalent to::

    [f(value) for f in list]

    If an element is not callable and not iterable, it is not called.
    An iterable is either directly appended or will be recursed through
    depending on recurse_level.

    Args:
        list_of_functions (list):
        value (any type):
        recurse_level (int):

    Returns:
        list:
    """
    new_list = []
    for possible_function in list_of_functions:
        try:
            new_list.append(possible_function(value))
        except TypeError: # item not callable; could be iterable
            # If it is iterable and recurse_level is not negative
            # recurse through elements
            if recurse_level >= 0:
                try:
                    new_list.append(through(possible_function,
                                            value,
                                            recurse_level))
                    recurse_level = recurse_level - 1
                except TypeError: # not an iterable; append without calling
                    new_list.append(possible_function)
            else:
                new_list.append(possible_function)
    return new_list
```

An example:

```
In: test = [[1, 2], [3, (lambda x : x ** 2)], (lambda x : x ** 3)]
In: through(test, 4, recurse_level=1)
Out: [[1, 2], [3, 16], 64]
In: through(test, 4, recurse_level=0)
Out: [[1, 2], [3, <function __main__.<lambda>>], 64]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some bugs.

- **Mutation of `recurse_level`:** Since you reassign `recurse_level = recurse_level - 1`, you get this weird behaviour:

  ```
  >>> through([[id], [id], [id], [id]], 'blah', recurse_level=2)
  [[4361400536], [4361400536], [4361400536], [<built-in function id>]]
  ```
- **Catching `TypeError`:** You catch `TypeError` here:

  > ```
  > try:
  >     new_list.append(possible_function(value))
  > except TypeError: # item not callable; could be iterable
  >     …
  > ```

  You are expecting that type `TypeError` might be thrown if `possible_function` is not callable.  But the exception handler could also be triggered by an exception within `possible_function` when it is being executed.  To be more precise, you should check for `callable(possible_function)` instead of catching `TypeError`.

  Similarly, your other `except TypeError` should be a check for the existence of `possible_function.__iter__`.

### Suggested solution

In the spirit of functional programming, you should write the code without `.append()` or other mutations.

Also note that using NumPy just for its infinity is overkill.

```
def through(functions, value, recurse_level=float('inf')):
    if callable(functions):
        return functions(value)
    elif recurse_level < 0 or not hasattr(functions, '__iter__'):
        return functions
    else:
        return [through(f, value, recurse_level - 1) for f in functions]
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Is it even overkill, If I import it anyway? I like ``np.infty`` a bit more to read than ``float('inf')``.

Comment: If you are already using NumPy then it's fine.

Comment: Perhaps you could  add ``or isinstance(functions, str) `` in your answer/code. I forgot about it in my function definition, which was a bug in my case and I think that most people intuitively would treat strings not as iterables in this context.

Answer (score 5):

## Naming

- In Clojure, there's a similar function named `juxt`.  Not saying that's a better name by any means, just mentioning what it happens to be called in one other place.  Upon further reflection, what you are doing is really just a recursive form of function application.  So a suitable name might reflect that.  Perhaps `apply_rec`?
- Use the shortest name that conveys sufficient meaning.  For example, `list_of_functions` could be shortened to `functions` (or even just `fs`).  `possible_function` could be shortened to `f`.  (Single-character names are not good names in general, but for generic entities that have a well-known mathematical notation, they are a good fit.)

## Use Better Checks for Callable / Iterable

You check if something's callable by trying to call it and catching a `TypeError` exception.  However, if you call a function, and that function happens to through a `TypeError`, then your code will incorrectly assume it's not a function.  You can use the `callable` function instead, to determine whether or not something is callable.

A similar situation exists in the way you check for iterables.  In this case, you can use the `iter` function as a fail-fast way to check if something's iterable.

## Consider Using a List Comprehension

Reading your code, I thought it was a bit ironic that you used a list comprehension in the docstring to describe the functions behavior, but not in the code itself.  Granted, due to the recursive nature, it's not quite as straight-forward.  But with just a little refactoring, it should be possible.  Here's how I would do it:

```
def apply_rec(f, x):
  """
  If f is a function, applies f to x and returns the result.
  Otherwise, if f is iterable, applies every element in f to x,
  returning a list of the results.
  If f is neither callable nor iterable, returns f.
  """

  if callable(f):
    return f(x)
  else:
    try:
      fs = iter(f)
    except:
      # Not iterable => return f
      return f

    return [apply_rec(f, x) for f in fs]
```

I've omitted the recursion limit, but that should be trivial to add.